# how to get all macvlan subinterfaces' MAC

Tags: linux, networking, docker

Is it possible to get all MAC/IPs for macvlan interface?
I have macvlan interface:

```
[root@srv ~]# ip a
    ..................
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
        link/ether 52:54:00:e7:e6:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    ......................
    4: macvlan0@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
        link/ether 52:54:00:e7:e6:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 1.1.0.6/24 brd 1.1.0.255 scope global macvlan0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and i have 16 docker containers with macvlan interfaces

```
[root@srv ~]# docker ps | grep 'Up ' |wc
     16     166    3512
[root@srv ~]#


[root@srv ~]# docker network inspect docker-net
............
        "Driver": "macvlan",
............
        "Containers": {
            "17ee78a594720836674448a244432e549ca4b78592e24767b2c6d052b783bd8e": {
......
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:64:00:f9",
                "IPv4Address": "1.1.0.249/24",
            },
            "1d910302d5fb83e478a0a5d70e0e566d89127916d9788cc61f6356502e14eb4e": {
........
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:64:00:ad",
                "IPv4Address": "1.1.0.173/24",
            },
            "2943fe549df8fd052d9f6ca74f720c11f7c7342d597d72a5287977d29c6f196f": {
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:64:00:eb",
                "IPv4Address": "1.1.0.235/24",
            },
```

how can i list ALL subinterfaces for macvlan0 ?

`ip netns` - show nothing

`lsns -t net` - show 16 docker's net namespaces

`arp -an` shows <16 arps, and some arps from other hosts (1.1.0.1,1.1.0.253,1.1.0.254)

```
[root@srv ~]# arp -an
? (1.1.0.1) at 00:00:0c:07:ac:1e [ether] on macvlan0
? (1.1.0.198) at 02:42:0a:64:00:c6 [ether] on macvlan0
? (1.1.0.238) at 02:42:0a:64:00:ee [ether] on macvlan0
? (1.1.0.253) at 7c:69:f6:d0:9a:81 [ether] on macvlan0
? (1.1.0.172) at 02:42:0a:64:00:ac [ether] on macvlan0
? (1.1.0.254) at 7c:69:f6:ba:a3:81 [ether] on macvlan0
? (1.1.0.173) at 02:42:0a:64:00:ad [ether] on macvlan0
? (1.1.0.234) at 02:42:0a:64:00:ea [ether] on macvlan0
? (1.1.0.174) at 02:42:0a:64:00:ae [ether] on macvlan0
? (1.1.0.235) at 02:42:0a:64:00:eb [ether] on macvlan0
? (1.1.0.249) at 02:42:0a:64:00:f9 [ether] on macvlan0
? (1.1.10.1) at 52:54:00:0e:84:51 [ether] on eth1
[root@srv ~]#
```

I understand, that all macvlan0 interfaces are in different net namespaces, and apparently  `ip link show macvlan0 show` can't show subinterfaces in different namespaces.
But is there other command to get all ip's and MAC's in all namespaces ?

Comment: You need to iterate over each namespace, and run `ip` in this namespace, e.g. `ip -n your_namespace addr show`. Not fun. What's wrong with `docker network inspect docker-net` instead?

Comment: I wonder why it is impossible to see all of MACs of particular macvlan interface.
And `ip -n` don't work, due empty of `/var/run/netns`
And i can have some macvlan subinterfaces inside docker, some not. So `docker network inspect` not best choice.
I want to have most general way to list all the MACs of particular macvlan in all namespaces (in docker or not)

Comment: Because I'd assume it's not a "particular macvlan inerface", it's a dozen interfaces in different namespaces which all happen to have the name `macvlan0`. So you need to iterate over all of those, one way or other. I haven't tried to access docker namespaces before, you may need the docker tools to run `ip` in that particular namespace.